# необходимо задать максимальную длину в 100 символов, в двух строчках по 50 используя inputTextarea

Tags: html, jsf

необходимо задать максимальную длину в 100 символов, в двух строчках по 50 используя inputTextarea. Получается сейчас оно печатает сколько угодно строчек, но по 50 символов. А нужно чтобы в конце второй строчки, то есть после сотого символа ввод ставал невозможным. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
<td>
    <h:inputTextarea style="height: 40px;resize: none" cols="50" rows="2" 
        value="#{component.entity.textRu}" id="textRu"
        title="#{cardOrderPurposesMsg.text_ru}" required="true"
        requiredMessage="#{commonMsg.empty_field_error}"/>
     <h:message for="textRu" styleClass="error"/>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Использовать стандартный h:inputTextarea совместно с валидатором. У пользователя будет возможность ввести более 100 символов, но при попытке подтверждения ввода в h:message будет выведено сообщение об ошибке.
2. Использовать JavaScript. У пользователя не будет возможности ввести более 100 символов, но при попытке ввода лишнего символа он будет появляться и тут же удаляться.
3. Использовать inputTextarea фреймворка Primefaces. Нет возможности ввести лишний символ, нет появления и исчезания вводимых символов.

Ниже пример кода, демонстрирующий все 3 варианта:

```
<html xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view>
<h:head/>

<h:body>
     <h:form>
        <h:inputTextarea style="height: 40px;resize: none" cols="50" rows="2"
                         value="#{bean.someString}" id="textRu"
                         required="true">
            <f:validateLength maximum="100"/>
        </h:inputTextarea>
        <h:message for="textRu" styleClass="error"/><br/>

        <h:inputTextarea style="height: 40px;resize: none" cols="50" rows="2"
                         value="#{bean.someString}" id="textRuJavascript"
                         onkeydown="limit(this, 100);" onkeyup="limit(this, 100);"
                         required="true"/><br/>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            function limit(element, max_chars) {
                if (element.value.length > max_chars) {
                    element.value = element.value.substr(0, max_chars);
                }
            }
        </script>

        <p:inputTextarea style="height: 40px;resize: none" cols="50" rows="2"
                         value="#{bean.someString}"
                         required="true" maxlength="100"/><br/>

        <h:commandButton value="OK"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```